# Using multiple **kwarg in Python with syntax def func(a,b, *, kwarg1, kwarg2)

Tags: python

I forgot where I saw a post before talking about how we can use this syntax `*` to give as many kwargs after it:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, *, kwarg1, kwarg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)
    for k, v in kwarg1.items():
        print(k, v)
    for k, v in kwarg2.items():
        print(k, v)
    return None

kwarg1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
kwarg2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
func(6,7, **kwarg1, **kwarg2)
```

The expected outout is:

```
6 7
a 1
b 2
e 5
d 4
c 3
f 6
```

But I get this error: `TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'`

I can have this version working, it's just I am interested in the above.

```
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwarg1):
    print(arg1, arg2)
    for k, v in kwarg1.items():
        print(k, v)
    return None

kwarg1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
kwarg2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
kwarg1.update(kwarg2)
func(6,7, **kwarg1)
```

Comment: You're _unpacking_ the two dictionaries to separate keyword arguments, but don't define anything that matches them - you have neither a catch-all `**kwargs` parameter nor explicit parameters for `a`, `b`, etc. Assuming the function _definition_ is correct maybe you meant `nc(6, 7, kwarg1=kwarg1, kwarg2=kwarg2)`, but there's no way (and it doesn't make sense) to have multiple _parameters_ for arbitrary kwargs - how would it decide which arguments ended up in which dictionary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That s an excellent remark! Thanks!

Comment: *"I saw a post before talking about how we can use this syntax * to give as many kwargs after it:"* You're maybe seeing the term "kwargs" and assuming that the writer means `**kwargs` in a function definition, but likely they're just using the term "kwargs" as shorthand for "keyword args".